# Collecting different values in a single input field

Tags: php, mysql

Guys i will be having only one input field. Where in i wanna ask the user to input either his phone no or his email to display his details from the database. How will i check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

any way you want really. E.g.:

```
if (strpos($input, '@')) {
    // process as email
} else {
    // process as phone number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: Check the user string for `@`. If it contains it, it is a email.

Answer (score 0):

The question... is quite incomplete, but I'll give it a try anyway...

1. Get all entries from the db, with the given phone number

   - `SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone = $phone`
2. If no rows are returned, then something went wrong (phone/user doesn't exist?)
3. If a row is returned, then fetch its other attributes (name/username/whatever...) and show them to the user

Answer (score 0):

find the user string for '@' char. 
If it contains it, it is a email otherwise phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

check for special character @ using strpos

```
if(isset($_POST['input']))
{ 
   $input =$_POST['input'];
   if(strpos($input,'@'))
   {
       $query="select * from tableName where email='$input'"; 
   }
   else
   {
        $query="select * from tableName where phone='$input'"; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Naveen- How to check for name and phone? Thanks. Do i need to put 'int' instead of '@'?

Comment: Basically you can provide checkbox depending on what is checked you can write your query.